# How do I insert data into a dbf format database using sql in Visual C# 2008?

Tags: c#, sql, dbf

How do I insert data into a `.dbf` format database using SQL in Visual c#?

Is it same as when using MS Access?

```
OleDbConnection dbConn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\wz\Desktop\UBS\onetimecapture\onetimecapture\onetimecapture\bin\Debug\;Extended Properties=dBase IV;");

try
{
   // Open connection.
   dbConn.Open();
   //string queryCutting = "INSERT INTO cuttingstatus.dbf ([Status]) VALUES(adddate)";
   string queryCutting = "INSERT INTO cuttingstatus.dbf VALUES(adddate)";
   OleDbCommand command_cutting = new OleDbCommand(queryCutting, dbConn);

   command_cutting.Parameters.AddWithValue("adddate", "123");
   command_cutting.ExecuteNonQuery();
   dbConn.Close();
}
catch
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error", "SCADA system", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
}
```

but it return an error say that

> The Microsoft Jet database engine could not find the object
>   'cuttings'.
>   Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly.

The database is called `cuttingstatus.dbf`, and it consist of only a single column `Status`.

Thanks for the help =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the name of the table in the `cuttingstatus.dbf`?

The statement should be something like:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME
VALUES(adddate)
```

as the value of the variable `queryCutting`.

Answer (score 0):

When making an OleDbConnection to use Database files, you want your connection source to point to the logical PATH WHERE the table is... not the actual table.

```
Connection dbConn = new OleDbConnection(@"Data ource=C:\SomePath\WhereAreAllTables;Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Extended Properties=dBase IV;");
```

Then, your insert query does not reference the .dbf extension... it is implied by the connection.  Also, even though it may be a single column, it would be better to explicitly show the column and values such as :

```
string queryCutting = "INSERT INTO cuttingstatus ( YourColumnName ) VALUES ( @adddate )";
```

Next...  Is it really a DBase IV system?   FoxPro table?  Clipper?   I would ensure proper provider.  If the data is actually from Foxpro origin, I would go to Microsoft and download the Visual Foxpro OleDb provider.

One final thought... is that the error is referring to a truncated table name of up to 8 characters "cuttings" which implies old DOS 8.3 file naming convensions.  Don't know if that is what you are also running into for your problem.

Comment: "OleDbConnection dbConn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=vfpoledb;Data Source=C:\\Users\\wz\\Desktop\\UBS\\onetimecapture\\onetimecapture\\onetimecapture\\bin\\Debug\\cuttingstatus.dbf;Mode=ReadWrite|Share Deny None;Collating Sequence=MACHINE;Password=''");"
may i know wat does it means? this, Collating Sequence=MACHINE